# How do you build the modified Toffoli gate using only local unitary and CNOT operations?

Tags: programming, quantum-gate, circuit-construction

How do you build a circuit for a modified Toffoli gate using only local unitary operations and CNOT operations? The two-qubit unitary operation is given by: $\text{diag}\{1, 1, 1, e^{i\phi}\}$.

Comment: You included the `programming` tag: are looking for some type of code implementation, or simply a mathematical derivation?

Comment: What do you mean by "modified toffoli"?